# springdoc swagger ui not showing entity component model schema

Tags: java, swagger-ui, spring-annotations, springdoc-openapi-ui

org.springdoc-openapi-ui version = **1.5.13** using **Maven 4.0.0**, **java 11**

model user.java

```java
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @NotBlank(message = "user last name cannot be blank")
    @NotEmpty(message = "user last name cannot be empty")
    @Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z]",message="last name must contain only alpha characters")
    private String lastName;
}
```

application.properties

```
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/api-docs.html
```

when going to :

> localhost:8080/api-docs.html

my other models (same architecture as User) are not showing.

Same if I go to

> localhost:8080/api-docs

other models are not in >components>schemas either

It used to work on my other projects (with same springdoc version)

Comment: So Entity User is nesting other entities (in a OneToMany, ManyToOne relationship).
Adding the right method (method to get the nested entity) to User class has brought back my entities in the docs.

Comment: Not marking the question as solved as the models aren't perfectly describing model as written in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities must have **set** and **get** methods of their properties that are nested entities in order for swagger ui to show the models of those other entities.
In my case I added the methods for nested entities I had in the context of **OneToMAny** and **ManyToOne** relationships and models showed